# ASP.Net MVC - Designing Views for Premium (Paid) Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have a service that is currently given away for Free!
Im now reaching the point where I have enough clients that I want to offer them a "Premium" Version.

So, some of "premium" features will include some extra text boxes on views.
I've built some custom attributes to handle security on the controller, but whats the best way to handle the view?
Should I create another view and present either the free of premium view?
Should I only have a single view? (if so how would I handle showing only certain text boxes\areas)

Suggestions and samples welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to make your main URL's very simple, and simply have them render a child action based on the membership level of the user.

Using HTML.Action() you can completely render a different view, and simply have your view look like this:

```
@model mymodel

@User.IsInRole("Premium") ? 
    Html.Action("PremiumView", "MyController") : 
    Html.Action("NormalView", "MyController")
```

If you have parameters, you can just pass them along.

Also, make sure you mark those subactions as Child Actions, using `[ChildActionOnly]` so they can't be accessed independently.

This way you can keep your free and premium versions totally separate but keep the same URLs.

You could also use Route Constraints to route to different controller actions based on various factors such as membership level.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view engine that supplied premium content when applicable, then name your views according (e.g. `MyView.cshtml` & `MyView.Premium.cshtml`). This gives you the flexibility to extend views with premium content while also not committing yourself to a major change up-front. You'll also need to validate when and when not to accept "premium" changes in the actions, but that should be simple role checking when you go to process.

Answer (score 0):

If your views contain more controls than your models are different and therefore your controllers are different, too. Your paid version may evolve at the different pace than the free version so I would suggest you keep the code separate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be best done on a per-view basis. If the free vs premium views are mostly the same with a few differences, then I would suggest using partial views within the main view checking the membership status for altering the display.

If there are major differences in the views for UI and functionality, then you might look at swapping out a different view entirely within the controller.